# NameError: name 'sum2' is not defined

Tags: python, pytest

I have a file *work.py*:

```
def sum(second_addend):
    def sum_operation(first_addend):
        return first_addend + second_addend
    return sum_operation


sum5 = sum(5)
print(sum5(10))
```

Now I want to test *work.py*.

*test.py*

```
import work


def test():
    try:
        return work.sum2(20)
    except NameError:
        return "NameError occurred. Some variable isn't defined."
```

I want to receive message "NameError occurred. Some variable isn't defined.", but I received "NameError: name 'sum2' is not defined"

I understand the point is in scope but I can't solve the problem.

Comment: You understand that the name isn't in scope but can't solve it? If you want a `sum2` name to be in scope, define a function called `sum2`. There's your solution. Or change `work.sum2(20)` to say `work.sum(20)` or reference some function that actually *does* exist

Comment: Are you **sure** the **exact** message you received was `NameError: name 'sum2' is not defined`?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the error message.  The actual error you get (or at least the error I got when I copied and pasted your code and ran it) isn't `NameError` but `AttributeError`.

```
C:test\python>python test.py
15
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test\python\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    test()
  File "C:\test\python\test.py", line 6, in test
    return work.sum2(20)
AttributeError: module 'work' has no attribute 'sum2'. Did you mean: 'sum'?
```

If your `except` is changed to catch `AttributeError` instead of `NameError`, you'll get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
test.py

```
import work


def test():
    try:
        return work.sum(20)
    except NameError:
        return "NameError occurred. Some variable isn't defined."
```